# Oracle PL/SQL - Identify and Extract Matching Words between two Strings

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

I'm fairly new to Oracle Functions so apologies for my naivety.

I was looking for a function that compares the string in `COL_A` with the string in `COL_B`, any matching words within the strings are then output to `COL_C`.

e.g.

- `COL_A = ‘Microsoft Office’`, `COL_B = ‘Windows Microsoft’`, therefore
  the expected result in `COL_C` would be `‘Microsoft’`
- `COL_A = ‘Microsoft Office’`, `COL_B = ‘Microsoft Office’`, therefore the
  expected result in `COL_C` would be `‘Microsoft Office’`
- `COL_A = ‘Microsoft Office’`, `COL_B = ‘Microsoft Windows'`, therefore the
  expected result in `COL_C` would be `‘Microsoft’`
- `COL_A = ‘Microsoft Office’`, `COL_B = ‘Outlook’`, therefore the expected
  result in `COL_C` would be `NULL`

I did find a Function that almost satisfies the requirement ([Count sequential matching words in two strings oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19270316/count-sequential-matching-words-in-two-strings-oracle)), however, this function outputs a count of matching words and only classifies a match where the word order also matches (for my purpose, the order is irrelevant and I would ideally like the matching word(s) to be displayed).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION STR_WORD_MATCH(
  P_STR1 IN VARCHAR2,
  P_STR2 IN VARCHAR2 )
 RETURN NUMBER
IS
 L_STR1 VARCHAR2(4000) := P_STR1;
 L_STR2 VARCHAR2(4000) := P_STR2;
 L_RES NUMBER DEFAULT 0;
 L_DEL_POS1 NUMBER;
 L_DEL_POS2 NUMBER;
 L_WORD1 VARCHAR2(1000);
 L_WORD2 VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
 LOOP
  L_DEL_POS1 := INSTR(L_STR1,' ');
  L_DEL_POS2 := INSTR(L_STR2,' ');
  CASE L_DEL_POS1
  WHEN 0 THEN
   L_WORD1 := L_STR1;
   L_STR1 := '';
  ELSE
   L_WORD1 := SUBSTR(L_STR1,1,L_DEL_POS1 - 1);
  END CASE;
  CASE L_DEL_POS2
  WHEN 0 THEN
   L_WORD2 := L_STR2;
   L_STR2 := '';
  ELSE
   L_WORD2 := SUBSTR(L_STR2,1,L_DEL_POS2 - 1);
  END CASE;
  EXIT
 WHEN (L_WORD1 <> L_WORD2) OR ((L_WORD1 IS NULL) OR (L_WORD2 IS NULL));
  L_RES := L_RES + 1;
  L_STR1 := SUBSTR(L_STR1,L_DEL_POS1 + 1);
  L_STR2 := SUBSTR(L_STR2,L_DEL_POS2 + 1);
 END LOOP;
RETURN L_RES;
END;
```

As always, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in one query, but to simplify syntax I created short function to split words. Next I used this function and `listagg()`:

```
select rn, max(c1) c1, max(c2) c2, 
       listagg(t2.column_value, ' ') within group (order by rn, c1, c2) common
  from (select rownum rn, c1, c2 from t) t 
  cross join table(split(c1)) t1 
   left join table(split(c2)) t2 on t2.column_value = t1.column_value
  group by rn
```

Function:

```
create or replace function split(i_str in varchar2) 
  return sys.odcivarchar2list pipelined is
begin
  for i in 1..length(' '||regexp_replace(i_str, '[^ ]+')) loop
    pipe row (regexp_substr(i_str, '[^ ]+', 1, i));
  end loop;
end;
```

Example:

```
with t (c1, c2) as (
    select 'Microsoft Office', 'Windows Microsoft' from dual union all
    select 'Microsoft Office', 'Microsoft Office'  from dual union all
    select 'Microsoft Office', 'Microsoft Windows' from dual union all
    select 'Microsoft Office', 'Outlook' from dual )
select rn, max(c1) c1, max(c2) c2, 
       listagg(t2.column_value, ' ') within group (order by rn, c1, c2) common
  from (select rownum rn, c1, c2 from t) t 
  cross join table(split(c1)) t1 
   left join table(split(c2)) t2 on t2.column_value = t1.column_value
  group by rn
```

Result:

```
        RN C1               C2                COMMON
---------- ---------------- ----------------- -----------------
         1 Microsoft Office Windows Microsoft Microsoft
         2 Microsoft Office Microsoft Office  Microsoft Office
         3 Microsoft Office Microsoft Windows Microsoft
         4 Microsoft Office Outlook
```